# Using Different Screw in Drywall Anchors

Tags: drywall, screws, studs, hanging, drywall-anchor

I have custom mounting hardware for a floating shelf I'm looking to install. This hardware came with its own special screws, which are meant to be screwed into wooden studs and support the mounting hardware with their protruding heads, which are designed uniquely for this purpose.

My studs are metal however, not wooden. So I thought to use drywall anchors as the solution.

The only problem is that drywall anchors all seem to come with their own specifically designed screws. But I need to use the special screws that came with my shelf mounting hardware.

**Can I use my own screws in drywall anchors? Has anyone done this before? Or, is there another solution entirely you'd recommend me?**

Here's what the special shelf mounting screws look like if that's helpful:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No one can tell you for sure since there are many varieties and sizes of drywall anchors.  I suggest you get some anchors which have screws roughly the same diameter as your shelf screws.  Then try them out in some inconspicuous spot on your wall. See if the anchors are holding firmly in the wall. You could even try mounting the shelf and testing it. Ultimately, it also depends on the weight of the items that will go on your shelf.

Comment: I too wanted to put a GRK screw part way into a wall anchor.  I tried a plastic anchor and when I pushed hard enough to seat the screw in the anchor, the anchor disappeared into the drywall. Next try was a metal EZAnchor style.  For the screw that was reasonably matched to the anchor, for the kitty litter scooper, it worked like a charm.  A screw several sizes larger for the dustpan eventually screwed its way into the anchor but it wasn’t pretty.  Next time I'd use a larger anchor for the larger screw.  But there is some flexibility and metal anchors do accept replacement screws.